# subprocess.call not acting as intended

Tags: java, python, bash, weka

I am trying to repeatedly execute an external program with python via the following code ...

```
3 javarun='java -classpath /home/jrm6u/code/weka_dir/weka.jar'
4 java1='java'
5 java2='-classpath'
6 java3='/home/jrm6u/code/weka_dir/weka.jar'
7 weka_args='weka.clusterers.DBScan'
8 db_type='weka.clusterers.forOPTICSAndDBScan.Databases.SequentialDatabase'
9 db_dist='weka.clusterers.forOPTICSAndDBScan.DataObjects.EuclidianDataObject'
```

...

```
28   traindir = './arff_dir/'
29   trainfile = 'of3_O_0_0.arff'
30   trainer = traindir + trainfile
```

...

```
45       subprocess.call([java1, java2, java3, weka_args, '-E', str(eps), '-M', str(min), '-I', db_type, '-D', db_dist, '-t', trainer], shell=True)
```

where eps and min are `0.125` and `10` respectively.

upon execution of my python code I get the following error:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
       (to execute a class)
or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
       (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
-d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
-d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
-server       to select the "server" VM
              The default VM is server.
```

with further output after. this is the exact same output i get upon entering simply `java` into the bash shell. this leads me to believe that, somehow, subprocess.call is not reading every single argument. is this case? how should i go about having it evaluate this command correctly?

note that this command can correctly be entered into the shell manually, but the motivation behind using this script is to have it loop through values of `min` and `eps` as well as training files so that i can execute these automatically.

Comment: You know you can just format the arguments as one string. try the exact string you ran in the shell and see what happens.

Comment: the problem with this is that i want to change some of the arguments so i am splitting them up to make them easier to change. java1, java2, java3 were initially one string and the same problem occured which made me split them up

Comment: you can always do the formatting yourself with `"%s %s %s..."`, but I suggested that as a debug step, not a solution. Also, I'd change the java arg to be the exact path of your java executable. BTW it's worth noting that you can integrate python and java without jython, using  this library: http://jpype.sourceforge.net/ or this one: https://github.com/thouis/Python-Java-Bridge

Comment: the `javarun` arg contains the exact path, along with `java3` and it DOES work when i have it all as one string ... what could be the problem?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `shell=True` here -- it's completely undoing your work at splitting up the argument list manually, and reprocessing it in a way which may or may not be correct. If it can't find `java` when `shell=False`, there's something funny with your OS environment (the PATH should still be searched in that case, and will typically contain the right thing), and identifying/fixing that underlying problem would be better, but you can try passing the explicit full path to the `java` executable as a stopgap.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's ignoring the parameters, but i'd try to avoid the Shell parameter unless necessary, sometimes it has weird behaviors (command-line parsing related, not python).

I'm know nothing about Java, but i bet you are giving it the wrong parameters, that output error is telling us nothing (except that `java` is found and it's not getting the correct parameters, it doesn't mean it's not getting any).

Try to debug the dictionary you are passing to subprocess.call (even with a simple print or `import pdb` and call to `pdb.set_trace()` to get a debugger in the previous line), and check if the command with those parameters is working as expected.

I know it is not a proper answer but this was too long for a comment line.

Comment: i am using the shell=True command because if i don't it tells me `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @Laurbert515 I think you are getting that error because 'java' isn't in your PATH, try using the fullpath to java or adding 'java' to your PATH system wide.